# C#: Add classes To an already existing library

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, dll

Is it possible to add a class (or wlasses) to an existing library. I want to use an ItemTemplateSelector in Windows Phone development and I know how to implement it but can I add it to System.Windows.Controls rathe than add it separately?

Comment: The closest you could come to adding to an existing framework library is to probably use [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx).  And that wouldn't really be adding it to the existing library.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating your component and re-use the namespace

```
namespace System.Windows.Control
{
   \\Put your code here
}
```

You will have a seperate dll, but it will belong to the same namespace.

However you should not do this. It is a bad practice to extend .Net Framework libraries and not recommended by Microsoft. The main reason for this is that changes in later version of the .Net Framework might collide with the changes.